# How to make convert a Month or Day to reflect as a 2 digit string using C#

Tags: c#

How does one convert a Month or Day to reflect as a 2 digit string using C#

For example : (02 instead of 2)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you have a `DateTime`, use [its string formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"); // or "dd" for day
```

Or if it makes more sense to work with a number that you have, use [the numeric formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
string monthStr = monthInt.ToString("00");
```

Comment: Thanks for including the dd!

Answer (score 9):

Use `"MM"` for double digits month and `"dd"` for double digits days.

```
string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
```

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: @Pinch In general date format strings are preferable over raw string manipulation. Great answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Comment: Why did you answer your own question immeidately after posting it with a *bad* solution.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot you have the option of including an answer when you post a question. People typically only do that if they have a good answer they like (or include their not-so-great solution in the question), but there's no law on that.